# Does changing the order of definite integration change the result?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, definition

Is the below true?

$$\int_{y_1}^{y_2}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(x,y)dxdy \overset{?}{=} \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\int_{y_1}^{y_2}f(x,y)dydx$$

Comment: Look up fubinis theorem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{y_1}^{y_2}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(x,y)dxdy \overset{?}{=} \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\int_{y_1}^{y_2}f(x,y)dydx$$
This in general is false, consider in fact $x_1=y_1=0$ and $x_2=y_2=1$ and define $f(x,y)$ as follow:
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} y^{-2}\quad \quad0<x<y<1 \\
-x^{-2} \quad \,0<y<x<1 \\
0 \quad\quad \quad\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$